# Git wont let rebase despite no diff

Tags: git, version-control

Not sure how it happened but today morning i tried rebasing my codebase and `.gitmodules` won't let that happen

**Terminal dump :**

```
~/codebase > git pull --rebase origin master
From https://gitlab.site.com/site/site
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    .gitmodules
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
could not detach HEAD

~/codebase > git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 75 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .DS_Store
    _test_certs/
    db_dump.sql
    dump.rdb
    local.py
    nohup.out


nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

`diff` also won't show any difference :

```
~/codebase > git diff
~/codebase >
```

Even tried `update-index --assume-unchanged` but din't worked :

```
~/codebase > git update-index --assume-unchanged .gitmodules
~/codebase > git pull --rebase origin master
From https://gitlab.site.com/site/site
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    .gitmodules
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
could not detach HEAD

~/codebase > git checkout master .gitmodules
error: pathspec '.gitmodules' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I tried checking out `.gitmodules` from `master`, even a `HARD reset`..no use...and since this file is in master as well, i cant rebase it...so cyclic issue...

Comment: `Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.` Your working directory is dirty.  Please take care of the `.gitmodules` file and then try your rebase again.  As an aside, your output also indicates that your local `master` is _way_ behind the remote, so yes a good healthy rebase is overdue ^ ^

Comment: i tried checking out `.gitmodules` from master..no use...and since this file is in `master` as well, i cant rebase it...so cyclic issue....get the point? :)

Comment: Did you try `git checkout -- .gitmodules` ?  Your previous `git checkout` command will not work I believe.

Comment: m not pro in git...but running `git checkout -- .gitmodules` as it is gives, `error: pathspec '.gitmodules' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: Try this: `git rm --cached -r .` followed by `git reset --hard`

Comment: that did the trick...mind explaining in an answer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard
```

The first command will remove all files from your working index, including the troublesome `.gitmodules` file.  The second command will reset the tip of your branch to point to the current `HEAD` of that branch.

GitHub's documentation has an [extremely valuable article](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) for dealing with the sort of situation you had.